# Google maps : Error when typing in coordinates of certain countries

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, cllocationmanager, google-geocoder

I'm drawing routes on `google map` and just realized it all works fine except I send coordinates of somewhere in Korea.(South to be precise)

`JSON` data is `null` even though the coordinates are correct and keeps "zero results"'ing me.

I've tried Africa, Australia, Europe and even China and Japan but anywhere in Korea won't work.

Am I missing something here..?

**EDIT**

So I guess it's not just Korea Mongolia and Indonesia are the same their geocodes don't work with waypoints to get the route.

Comparing results between Korea and Germany -

*Korea*

```
{"geocoded_waypoints" : [
  {
     "geocoder_status" : "OK",
     "place_id" : "ChIJzWXFYYuifDUR64Pq5LTtioU",
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "geocoder_status" : "OK",
     "place_id" : "ChIJNc0j6G3raDURpwhxJHTL2DU",
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
  }],"routes" : [],"status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"}
```

*Germany*

```
{"geocoded_waypoints" : [
  {
     "geocoder_status" : "OK",
     "place_id" : "ChIJAVkDPzdOqEcRcDteW0YgIQQ",
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]},
  {
     "geocoder_status" : "OK",
     "place_id" : "ChIJ2V-Mo_l1nkcRfZixfUq4DAE",
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]}],"routes" : [
  {
     "bounds" : {
        "northeast" : {
           "lat" : 52.5200138,
           "lng" : 13.404945
        },
        "southwest" : {
           "lat" : 48.1351972,
           "lng" : 11.1954806
        }
     },
     "copyrights" : "Datos de mapas ©2015 GeoBasis-DE/BKG (©2009), Google",
     "legs" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "585 km",
              "value" : 584740
           },
```

And so on and on. As you see you get full data with german coordinates.

**EDIT**

Ok..`CLLocationManager` does the same thing... How am I supposed to get addresses in those countries??

Comment: Can you clarify what results you are usually getting/expecting?

Comment: I send latitude/longitude of start/end points and then draw routes between two points. It works with most countries but does not with a few countries and I'm not entirely sure whether that's just the way it is, meaning that they just have strong restrictions and I just can't make it OR I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: What data are you getting in other countries exactly that you aren't getting in Korea or Mongolia?

Comment: I get empty JSON data with status = ZERO RESULTS. Doesn't happen with the most countries tho. But the ones that don't work, never work no matter what part of the country.

Comment: @duranzo - I just tried Korea using google's reverse geocode service and it worked fine for some random coordinates in South Korea, can you specify what data doesn't work? My example coords are : 37.532600,127.024612

Comment: I can find a place with coordinates that's no issue. The issue is to get address or distance between a place and somewhere in above mentioned countries or estimated time of arrival by walking etc. I can only locate a spot, not able to get information. **Actually** a couple of days ago I found an article about Google trying to convince Korea to let people share info using Google Maps.. so I guess that explains how I'm just supposed to let users know that it isn't available due to restrictions whenever user tries to get routes in those countries..? What else can I do?

Comment: Apparently, Korea imposes several restrictions to use of maps on internet:
> Google is pressuring South Korea to ease up on regulations that make
> it impossible for the company to offer driving directions through
> Google Maps 
> from **The Verge** http://www.theverge.com/tech/2013/10/13/4835026/why-google-cant-give-you-driving-directions-in-south-korea
More details: http://www.nytimes.com/2013/10/14/business/international/google-jousts-with-south-koreas-piecemeal-internet-rules.html?_r=0

[]'s

Comment: I'd really like to know how some apps provide route directions in Korea. Seriously can't find anything on that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that many countries in the Middle East, Africa, Northern Europe, Korea, and some areas in Asia actually do not have any information. You cannot find routes through them. I was playing around by trying to find the longest distance walkable, so I tried to walk to Cape Town from Europe through the Middle East, and it couldn't calculate it. I really don't see why though. I think you're right about what your problem is. @durazno

Comment: The thing is on their Korean website they claim to have functional route direction service in Korea. I'm so very confused.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
{
    CLLocation *pinLocation =[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:position.target.latitude  longitude:position.target.longitude];

CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:pinLocation
               completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error)
     {
         return;
     }
     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
     NSLog(@"address-->%@",placemark.addressDictionary);
```

}];